# Django class based views - no module named base

Tags: django, django-views

I'm having a problem trying to use class based views in django.
When I try to import the base View I get an import error.

I've simplified my view down to the exact same code as used in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.base import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

The error I'm getting is

```
ImportError at /myurl/
No module named base
```

urls.py are fine and Django is definitely version 1.5 - I've completely reinstalled it with pip, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of @dm03514 comment I test it. I try your code in your question and I got the same error with you **"No module named base"**. So when I change it to, like the codes below, it works and no error.

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
```

Try before judging, I will accept it if it is wrong and I will try to fix it.

Comment: @dm03514 It doesn't look?? but have you tried it?? my code above is working but I'm not sure if that 'View' is what he want to call in MyView function. Try first before judging...

Comment: many thanks for that.
I'll issue a pull request to django to change the docs, I wonder if this has changed in 1.5.